# Is it possible to slow down IIS?

Tags: iis, web-applications, iis-7, webserver

I have a local development webserver set up using Win7 and IIS7.

I often have to test the applications and websites I develop on all browsers using "very slow" internet connections to determine how all the clients scripts execute and if the images and all linked resources load properly and in order on all browsers.

Now, this involves deploying the project to a remote server and then testing over a slow internet or network connection. In my case this is usually only possible at the end of the project. Its a pain to deploy the project every now and then only for speed testing ...

Is it possible to slow down IIS so it behaves like you're connected over a very slow internet connection and test the applications that way. This will also help me test the applications on a standalone PC (without a network of PCs) like on a home desktop that doesn't have a network connection only an internet connection.

Sorry for sounding newbie-ish ! ... couldn't help because I am one :)

Thanks,
Norman.

**UPDATE:** Almost all answers to this question were great and work in different situations .... for me (IIS7 on Win7) the selected answer is the most appropriate ... I'm sure you'll find an answer here that works for you :). So thanks to everyone ... oh ... and don't be surprised if the next version of IIS or VS ships with magnets ! :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) has an option to [throttle speeds locally](http://groups.google.com/group/httpfiddler/browse_thread/thread/264de732c393805b) as well which might be a bit more convenient.

Comment: +1 for the reference to Fiddler.  This may prove quite useful in the future.

Comment: interesting .... can Fiddler be used on top of a local IIS7 installation or do you have to be on a network for the "Simulate Modem" to work ?

Comment: @Norman - Fiddler runs client side as a proxy server so you could use it to slow down traffic to your browsers on your development machine.

Comment: For newbies like me: The linked code can be found in Fiddler through Rules > Customize Rules... And it's activated with Rules > Performance > Simulate Modem Speeds

Answer (score 9):

[Enabling Bandwidth Throttling (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/83d66f47-8184-4d25-afcf-c229fffdc981.mspx?mfr=true)

[IIS 7.0 Bit Rate Throttling Module Released](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/03/18/iis-7-0-bit-rate-throttling-module-released.aspx)

Comment: IIS 7.X Bit Rate Throttling is as I now only for media streaming ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can also change the network adapter settings on your PC. For example, changing the MTU size can greatly affect network performance. Increasing MTU size to a large amount can increase lag/latency, whereas decreasing it will usually decrease your bandwidth.

Alternately, you could just set a large magnet on top of your Ethernet cable. The interference should cause a lot of packets to have to be resent, thus decreasing your effective bandwidth.

**Edit:** Apparently [a strategically placed microwave](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3116531/Dueling-with-Microwave-Ovens.htm) can also reduce network throughput by a whopping 85%. So there's another alternative for the WiFi folks.

Comment: hmmm .... Magnet .... interesting :) ... +1 for an innovative solution !  -- I'm sure a lot of ppl would be looking for magnets now .... shoud be part of a developer toolkit :D

Comment: And if you're using a wireless connection you can just cook a bunch of hotpockets next to your computer =P.

Comment: "dual HD touchscreens, with a quad-core PC, a 2000 Watt microwave and a 100 Tesla magnet ... now that's what you call a workstation !"

Comment: Don't forget to put a Faraday cage around the whole thing--wouldn't want to catch some accidental interference from your cellphone.

Comment: "a strategically placed microwave"... man, debugging is definitely advancing... ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can always use a Firefox add-on (e.g. [Firefox Throttle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5917/)) for throttling your browser instead of throttling the server.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a stab in the dark.  I use NetLimiter on my machine to throttle my download manager (a separate application).  That may prove useful.  Note, it's a trialware application.  Mitch Wheat's answer may be more appropriate.