# How to simulate slow page load in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to simulate slow page load in ASP.NET?

Comment: For what purpose/from what cause?

Comment: @joel , Purpose: related set of events that precede  this page load...are currently being tuned due to slow performance...but still wanna check the sweet spot or tolerability limit for this page...in terms of time out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) can be used to simulate modem ([or other slow speed connections](http://groups.google.com/group/httpfiddler/browse_thread/thread/264de732c393805b))

Related Question: [Is it possible to slow down IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173318/is-it-possible-to-slow-down-iis/3173334#3173334)

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to add in the page load event handler

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(numberOfMillisecondsToDelay);
```

Comment: No way - totally diferent behavior.

Comment: This will simulate latency, but not low bandwidth.

Comment: +1 because although this doesn't answer the question, it was exactly what I needed in order to simulate latency.

Answer (score 5):

if your application is x-browser you could use a firefox add-on, like Firefox Throttle

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5917/

or maybe just use firefox for testing if your web application targets a specific browser

Update (9/15/2012): This plugin is no longer active... "This add-on has been disabled by an administrator."

Answer (score 4):

Bandwidth or Latency?

For bandwidth, you can use the Bandwidth Throttling module for [IIS6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/83d66f47-8184-4d25-afcf-c229fffdc981.mspx?mfr=true) or [IIS7](http://blogs.iis.net/rakkimk/archive/2008/04/04/iis7-configure-throttling-for-your-documents-any-mime-type-and-save-bandwidth-costs.aspx).

Not sure how to simulate high Latency though.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at Visual Studio's performance testing capabilities.

Here's a quick guide:

http://vsptqrg.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to determine how your site or app behaves under high load? If so I can recommend [jMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/). The advantage of this approach is that you can create different groups of threads which can approximate the behaviour of real users hitting your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Chrome. There is a native function on the browser. Press F12 and go to Network tab.

[image]